# Replace first occurrence within file using python

Tags: python-2.7

So i'm trying to replace a "'pleb'" within the python file itself. When i activate the code, however it replaces 2 of the 3 occurrences rather than the first.

```
rank_mod = ['pleb']

f1 = open('C:\Python27\Scripts\bot\bot.py', 'r')
                            f2 = open('C:\Python27\Scripts\bot\bot.py', 'w')
                            for line in f1:
                                f2.write(line.replace("'pleb'", "'" + username + "', 'pleb'", 1))
                            f1.close()
                            f2.close()
```

When this is activates it looks like this:

```
rank_mod = ['(the username)', 'pleb']

f1 = open('C:\Python27\Scripts\bot\bot.py', 'r')
                            f2 = open('C:\Python27\Scripts\bot\bot.py', 'w')
                            for line in f1:
                                f2.write(line.replace("'(the username)' , 'pleb'", "'" + username + "', 'pleb'", 1))
                            f1.close()
                            f2.close()
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the issue is but it may be due to behavior caused by opening the same file for reading and writing. Try this:

```
rank_mod = ['pleb']
f1 = open('C:\Python27\Scripts\bot\bot.py', 'r')
contents = f1.read().replace("'pleb'","'" + username + "', 'pleb'", 1)
f1.close()
f1 = open('C:\Python27\Scripts\bot\bot.py', 'w')
f1.write(contents)
f1.close()
```

Comment: Sadly this just crashes the script.

Comment: Oh, I figured you had defined username somewhere else in your script. If its not defined before, you need to first define this variable. Otherwise, this should work. If not, please report what error message you are getting to better help diagnose the issue.